# setExact not really exact up to Android 5.0.2

Tags: android

I am not quite sure whether it is a problem of my Nexus 5 mobile phone or I understand it wrong.
Before Android 4.4/5.0 I always used setRepeaping for scheduling new alarms in due time and it always worked.
But since Android 4.4 I have to use setExact and therefore I create a dictionary with all alarms and then one alarm after the other will be triggered. However, I encountered the following problem: the first 2 alarms are more or less precise ( first alarm is 7 seconds too late, 2nd alarm is already 30 seconds too late, and sometimes the 3rd alarm that will be triggered after one hour will be triggered two minutes too late or sometimes it will never be triggered! ).
When I read the documentation I can see that it is written there that setExact tries to be as precise as possible.

Am I right that setExact is not really exact, can be but need not to be?
If so then I will have to implement an IntentService that will check my dictionary every minute and this IntentService will trigger the alarm in due time.
Will the OS interrupt an IntentService when there is not enough RAM or something like that ( if that should ever happen, then it will be a problem that the user has to solve in the end, too many running apps, etc :) )?

Thank you very much for your help!